# What is "Boeing Agile Software Process?"

Tags: agile

I was surfing the web, and I came across the term "Boeing Agile Software Process," but I was unable to find a definition or any details. Presumably, this is the software process used at Boeing and it's Agile, but could anyone explain what the Boeing Agile Software process is/was?

Comment: I get how technically this question was asking for an off-site resource, but judging from the provided answer it seems like it's not attracting opinionated answers or spam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the first several pages of the paper:

> "A Tail of Two Projects: How 'Agile'
>   Methods Succeeded After 'Traditional'
>   Methods Had Failed in a Critical
>   System-Development Project"

that Robert Bedoll wrote about agile methods at Boeing and published for XP/Agile Universe 2003 [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=Dot2BhbeEiwC&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=Boeing+Software+Process+agile&source=bl&ots=9XzL1sthk0&sig=IkWoZSLJa4mKbpdYnGzGZhgCWJQ&hl=en&ei=fKhVTdyNGIKglAekqoSrBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&sqi=2&ved=0CEoQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=Boeing%20Software%20Process%20agile&f=false), on Google Books. Here's a summary:

> We adopted the following principles:
>
> - Rapid prototyping of designs, with immediate customer feedback
> - Continuous involvement of the customer Weekly production releases:
>     Follow our standard development cycle 
>     (requirements - design – code – test -
>     release) but compress it from formal
>     releases every three months to formal
>     releases every week.
> - Start    simple and keep it simple
> - Evolve the tool to follow the evolving business process
> - Provide a one to three week cycle time for new feature introduction
> - Maintain a small development team
> - Produce abbreviated versions of our standard design documents.Let the
>     prototyping drive    the design
>     documentation.
> - Retain our SEI (Software Engineering Institute) Level 2 rating.

It looks like there's a draft "*not yet been formally approved by Boeing for publication*" in .doc format [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCwQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cems.uwe.ac.uk%2F~cjwallac%2FISD3%2Fbedoll.doc&rct=j&q=robert%20bedoll%20%22immediate%20customer%20feedback%22&ei=MqxVTafqH4jDgQfxmoDDDA&usg=AFQjCNHaUhA9ucnQfSXwOuQo_ofJ_WUd4A&sig2=Hi2UW3CG9Vz6wMExr8Q0Ow&cad=rja), that explains the principles in more detail. I'm not not a lawyer and don't know if there are legal implications if one were to read that draft. You can buy the whole published paper as a .pdf [here](https://springerlink3.metapress.com/content/6rcdka4adh5bdabb/resource-secured/?target=fulltext.pdf&sid=sloeo3y114rie3450nynnd55&sh=www.springerlink.comhttps://springerlink3.metapress.com/content/6rcdka4adh5bdabb/resource-secured/?target=fulltext.pdf&sid=sloeo3y114rie3450nynnd55&sh=www.springerlink.com) and probably other places.